# Function won't run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get this code to run at all. The console.log doesn't even run. Please help.

```
function showHistory(){
    $("#history").text("");
    for(var i = 0; i < searchHistory.length; i++){
        const historyItem = $("#history").add("<input>");
        $("historyItem").attr("type","text");
        $("historyItem").attr("readonly",true);
        $("historyItem").attr("class", "form-control d-block bg-white");
        $("historyItem").attr("value", searchHistory[i]);
        $("#history").append(historyItem);
    } 
    console.log("TEST")
}
```

Comment: None of this code runs anything. It defines a function; it doesn't execute it. You'd have to have another line that calls `showHistory()` somewhere.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `(function() {
   // your page initialization code here

})();`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a function to run, you need to invoke it after defining it. In your case, you should add the line showHistory() to the file. The parentheses indicate that you are executing the function.

Comment: If you did invoke the function, and are getting errors, please list them

Answer (score 0):

searchHistory should be defined if not already.

Comment: I mean it is defined in the example, it just isn't being executed/called